# aiohttp or playwright API fail where requests or request-html does not. I don't understand why

Tags: python, async-await, python-requests, playwright, aiohttp

I am trying to use aiohttp to make some async requests but they keep failing. Since I was first getting cookies via playwright, I decided to try playwright's API to make the same requests, yet those were failing too.
I then tried python's requests module and those were working fine. I finally tried request-html async and those worked fine too.
What is going on? I have not been able to understand why synchronous requests via "requests" or async via requests-html work fine, but when I try aiohttp or playwright the request just gets stuck and I never get an error. It simply timesout after several seconds.

Given that all the parameters are **exactly** the same, I am only copying the actual request statement for all four libraries I am using.

```
#requests-html - THIS WORKS
rs = AsyncHTMLSession()
for cookie in cookies:
    rs.cookies.set(cookie["name"],cookie["value"])
SM_r = await rs.get(API_URL,params=query_params[0],headers=HEADERS)
SA_r = await rs.get(API_URL, params=query_params[1], headers=HEADERS)
OP_r = await rs.get(API_URL, params=query_params[2], headers=HEADERS)
print(SM_r.json())
print(SA_r.json())
print(OP_r.json())
await rs.close()

#requests - THIS WORKS (but it is slow since it is not async)
r = requests.Session()
for cookie in cookies:
    r.cookies.set(cookie["name"],cookie["value"])
SM_r = r.get(API_URL,params=query_params[0],headers=HEADERS)
SA_r = r.get(API_URL, params=query_params[1], headers=HEADERS)
OP_r = r.get(API_URL, params=query_params[2], headers=HEADERS)
print(SM_r.json())
print(SA_r.json())
print(OP_r.json())
r.close()

#aiohttp - DOES NOT WORK
session_cookies = {}
for cookie in cookies:
    session_cookies[cookie["name"]] = cookie["value"]
as = aiohttp.ClientSession(cookies=session_cookies)
SM_r = await as.get(API_URL, params=query_params[0], headers=HEADERS)
SA_r = await as.get(API_URL, params=query_params[1], headers=HEADERS)
OP_r = await as.get(API_URL, params=query_params[2], headers=HEADERS)
print (await SM_r.json())
print (await SA_r.json())
print (await OP_r.json())
await s.close()

#playwright's API - Note I used playwright in headless to retrieve the cookies and headers I am using in all methods, so this one should work out of the gate, but for some reason, like aiohttp, it simply times out.

SM_r = await api_request.get(API_URL,params=query_params[0])
assert response.ok
print (await SM_r.json())
```

Can someone spot the issue or can someone please explain what is it in this particular request that aiohttp and playwright do not work?

Thanks